# Unity C# Grid based movements and positioning of a player in a grid?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, grid

How do you detect where in a grid an object is? I'm currently trying to find how to map my player to my grid locations, and am having trouble figuring out what to do. I'm working in Unity 3d, and have created a script that creates a chessboard grid upon startup, and names each tile according to its position in the grid

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GridCreation : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int height = 7;
    public int width = 7;
    public GameObject prefabPlane;
    public GameObject prefabPlane2;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject newObject;
        for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++ ) {
                if ((i + j) % 2 == 0)
                    newObject = Instantiate(prefabPlane, new Vector3(i * 10 , 0, j * 10),Quaternion.identity);
                 else 
                    newObject = Instantiate(prefabPlane2, new Vector3(i * 10, 0,j * 10 ),Quaternion.identity);
                newObject.name = i + "," + j;
                
            }
        }

    }
```

The script above is attached to an empty object. I have a separate script attached to the player for movement that I am currently working on setting up as well that successfully maps to the correct positions, but only because it is properly set within the Unity Space. It isn't able to return information based on where on the grid it is. Ultimately what I'd like to be able to do is locate position of player in grid, and when a key is pressed (w,a,s,d), set position of player either (i + 1, j), or (i, j +1) in the grid

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add a Collider2D to the tiles, and check which tile it is on:

```
RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector3(playerTransform.position.x, playerTransform.position.y, -10), Vector2.zero);
```

To move the player, add to the position ± 10 for each coordinate. For example, to go a to the top box: `transform.position.y + 10`